# Graph API not returning dynamic groups for a user

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

When I query the group via the API or Graph Explorer, I see the user listed as the first user.  This is a dynamic security group.

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{groupId}?$expand=members`

However, when I query the user to get all of their group memberships, this dynamic group is not included in the list of groups.

I have tried both memberOf and transitiveMemberOf

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{userId}?$expand=transitiveMemberOf`
`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{userId}?$expand=memberOf`

I do get back other groups for the user, just not this dynamic group.  Is there something I am missing to get it to include all the user's dynamic groups?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are ok with using a call specifically for getting group membership (instead of the user profile itself), you can use this url instead:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{userid}/memberOf`

I just tested it myself, and was able to grab groups that were dynamic. I'm not totally sure about the difference in just using the `$expand` parameter vs the `/memberOf` endpoint, but that should get you what you're looking for.

Update: This url will list only *DynamicMembership* groups, to simplify validating the expected response. It also uses te `beta` api instead of *v1.0*.

`https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/{user id}/memberOf/microsoft.graph.group?$count=true&$orderby=displayName&$filter= groupTypes/any(c:c+eq+'DynamicMembership')&$Select=displayName,groupTypes,membershipRule`

Comment: I get the same results using /memberOf as well.  It does show one dynamic group for the user, but not the one that I am looking for in this case.  And I have verified again that the user is definitely listed, with the same object id, in this other dynamic group.

Comment: If you try this query, do you see what you’re looking for? 

https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/{user id}/memberOf/microsoft.graph.group?$count=true&$orderby=displayName&$filter= groupTypes/any(c:c+eq+'DynamicMembership')&$Select=displayName,groupTypes,membershipRule

Comment: Thanks Michael.  After querying against the Beta version, the role then started to show up in the v1.0 using the /userid/memberOf.  It definitely was not there yesterday, so I am wondering if something gets cached for dynamic groups and querying it via the beta version caused it to refresh.  The original approach I was taking with the expand option still doesn't return that dynamic group even though it does return another dynamic group.   Thanks for the assist.